# Starcraft 2: Void Ray Micro

Tags: starcraft-2

In theory the void ray can move while attacking.  Is it possible to attack a stationary (non moving target) while moving your void ray?  Or does the void ray have to be attacking a moving target?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So the way attack moving as a void ray works is as follows:

- If a Void Ray is attacking and you issue a move command it will continue attacking its target.
- If you issue an attack/move command it will stay in place and attack its target.  \
- A Void Ray will not attack while moving backwards (as the Phoenix does)
- If its target moves the Void will stay in place till the target is out of range and then move up into range before attacking its target again, at which point it will become stationary until the target moves out of range.

The practical result of these rules is that you have no control over what the Void Ray targets while moving (similar to the Phoenix).  If the target its chasing goes out of range (or dies) the Void Ray will independently choose its target.  To remedy this do the following:

1. Select the target you want to attack (either <kbd>A</kbd>-click or Right Click an enemy).
2. Issue a *Move* command to the Void Ray (either <kbd>M</kbd>-click or Right Click empty ground).
3. If the target becomes out of Range or the Void Ray passes it, you must reselect the target to Attack it.